# dynamic jquery header

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I would like to do a header in my homepage having different images and that they will continuously change dynamically between the various images using jquery.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unless this is specifically generating dynamic content using C#, you might get better success tagging it with jQery instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need a [**Carousel**](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/01/jquery-carousel.html)

Here is an example [**Demo**](http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/)

### ASPX Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    abc();
    var index = 0;
    var images = [
                        'Chrysanthemum.jpg',
                        'Jellyfish.jpg',
                        'Penguins.jpg',
                        'Lighthouse.jpg'
                    ];
    function abc() {

        images = [
                        'Chrysanthemum.jpg',
                        'Jellyfish.jpg',
                        'Penguins.jpg',
                        'Lighthouse.jpg'
                    ];
        $('img').attr('src', images[0]);
        setInterval(change_image, 2000);

    }
    function change_image() {
        if (index >= images.length) index = 0;

        $('img').attr('src', images[index]);
        index++;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: In case the images are present in root directly then this is the code otherwise you can simply append the folder name.

Comment: Yes, thats I understood. My question is, where am I going to call the function of change_image()? so that on page load it will be automatically done without any buttons

Comment: it will be called automatically. This job is being done by setInterval function. So this function will be automatically called after 5000 milliseconds. You just have to paste this code in your ASPX page.

Comment: OK ok I understood. Thanks very much!! Listen last question, I am using content place holder for my website which inherits from master page, will it make any difference for the jquery?

Comment: The reason I didn't done it before because I am knew to stack overflow and I didn't have enough reputation score to do so.

Comment: Now could you please tell what difference it makes if I inherit from master page and I am using content place holder

Comment: At one side you have a header common using master page and at other hand you are writing the same header HTML in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of jQuery image sliders/rotators - do a quick Google search or use one of these?

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/01/jquery-image-slider.html

Answer (score 0):

There many ways, but something like this will get you started.

```
var index = 0;
var images = [
    'image-0.jpg',
    'image-1.jpg',
    'image-2.jpg',
    'image-3.jpg'
];

$('img#image').attr('src', '/path/' + images[0]);

setInterval(change_image, 5000);

function change_image() {
    index++;
    if (index >= images.length) index = 0;

    $('img#image').attr('src', '/path/' + images[index]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am a bit new to jquery. I am using an image option to do my header. How would I call this function then from the image?

Answer (score 0):

So if you have fixed number of images you can get them with jQuery and just loop through them:
var bannerNum = 0;

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/GetImagesList.aspx',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(d) {
       var intNum = setInterval(5000, function(d){
          if(bannerNum > d.Images.length)
             bannerNum = 0;
          $('#your_image_id').attr('src', d.Images[bannerNum].Src);
          $('#your_image_id').parent().attr('href', d.Images[bannerNum].Href);
          bannerNum++;
       });
   }
});
```

What I have done, I have requested list of banners from server, then I have created timeout which will be executed every 5 seconds and it will change attribute src of image and href of link.

Next, in C# load list of banners and put them in list then convert that list into JSON using JavaScript serializer and write it to response.

e.g.

```
public class VOBanner {
    public string Src { get; set; } 
    public string Href {get; set; }
}
```

**Logic**

```
//Load data from db
List<VOBanner> banners = new List<VOBanner>();
foreach(DataRow rw in datatable.Rows)
{
   banners.Add(new VOBanner { Src = rw["Src"].ToString(), Href = rw["Href"].ToString() });
}
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Response.Clear();
Response.Write(serializer.serialize(new { Images = banners } );
Response.End();
```

And that would be basic logic.

I hope this helps...